# How to get duration in minutes with overlapping time ranges using BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table in BigQuery contains `device` ids, `event_type`, `start_time` and `end_time` of the event.
I need to calculate total device activity duration taking note of overlapping time ranges
I can get time difference for each event at each device but no idea how to get real duration,

```
WITH sessions as (SELECT 1222 device, 1 event_type, DATETIME(2021,02,02,10,00,00) start_time, DATETIME(2021,02,02,10,10,00) end_time
UNION ALL 
SELECT 1222 , 2 , DATETIME(2021,02,02,10,05,00) , DATETIME(2021,02,02,11,00,00) 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 1222 , 1 , DATETIME(2021,02,02,10,20,00) , DATETIME(2021,02,02,10,30,00) 
UNION ALL
SELECT 1333 , 1 , DATETIME(2021,02,02,11,00,00) , DATETIME(2021,02,02,11,30,00) 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 1333 , 2 , DATETIME(2021,02,02,11,35,00) , DATETIME(2021,02,02,11,40,00) 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 1333 , 1 , DATETIME(2021,02,02,11,50,00) , DATETIME(2021,02,02,11,55,00) )
SELECT device, event_type ,start_time ,end_time, DATETIME_DIFF(end_time, start_time ,MINUTE ) FROM sessions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below option

```
select device, sum(datetime_diff(end_time, start_time ,minute)) duration                   
from (
  select device, time_range, min(start_time) start_time ,max(end_time) end_time, 
  from (
    select device, start_time, end_time,
      countif(new_range) over(partition by device order by start_time) time_range
    from (
      select device, event_type ,start_time ,end_time, 
        ifnull(start_time >= lag(end_time) over(partition by device order by start_time), true) new_range
      from sessions
    )
  )
  group by device, time_range
)
group by device
```

if applied to sample data in  your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For every row we can take a look at the `end_time` of the previous row. If it is larger than current row's `start_time` then we can use it instead to calculate duration. Some durations will be negative because previous row's `end_time` can be greater than current row's `end_time`, so we summarize all positive durations.

```
WITH sessions AS (
  SELECT 1222 device, 1 event_type, DATETIME(2021,02,02,10,00,00) start_time, DATETIME(2021,02,02,10,10,00) end_time UNION ALL 
  SELECT 1222 , 2 , DATETIME(2021,02,02,10,05,00) , DATETIME(2021,02,02,11,00,00) UNION ALL 
  SELECT 1222 , 1 , DATETIME(2021,02,02,10,20,00) , DATETIME(2021,02,02,10,30,00) UNION ALL 
  SELECT 1333 , 1 , DATETIME(2021,02,02,11,00,00) , DATETIME(2021,02,02,11,30,00) UNION ALL 
  SELECT 1333 , 2 , DATETIME(2021,02,02,11,35,00) , DATETIME(2021,02,02,11,40,00) UNION ALL 
  SELECT 1333 , 1 , DATETIME(2021,02,02,11,50,00) , DATETIME(2021,02,02,11,55,00) 
),
calculated_duration AS (
  SELECT 
    *,
    DATETIME_DIFF(
      end_time,
      IFNULL(
        GREATEST(
          start_time,
          LAG(end_time) OVER(PARTITION BY device ORDER BY start_time)
        ),
        start_time
      ),
      MINUTE
    ) AS duration
  FROM sessions
)
SELECT device, SUM(GREATEST(duration, 0))
FROM calculated_duration
GROUP BY device
```

[image]